# Drawing Tables with scripts or programs in lotus notes

Tags: csv, lotus-notes, userscripts

I need to send our report on daily basis. is there any way I can automate it?

It was about 10 csv file, all I need to do is to get the first line of all of them and make a table and send to a pre-defined list of peoples.

Comment: so far i can create email with vbscript (w / lotus extension). which actually handle the csv file io and also create and send email in lotus notes, but i still have no way to get the Notes drawing tables .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you pointed in the right direction, you will need to be using the NotesRichTextTable class, and the AppendTable method of the NotesRichTextItem class. You can find documentation for all of these in the Domino Designer help files, or [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESRICHTEXTITEM_CLASS.html).

Comment: thanks, my old pdf file just do not have such information.   http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg244856.pdf

Comment: not even in version 7, http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/uafiles.nsf/docs/ls70/$file/lscript.pdf

Comment: If you need to do this in version 7, then you may have to look at the Midas Rich Text API from Genii Software. (Note, however, that this is not free software.)

Comment: i have draw the table now, now i need to get the column width works, but unfortunately, it seems that i am unable to build that paragraph styles array.